# Menu bootstrap 4 com duas linhas

Tags: bootstrap-4

Como fazer menu bootstrap 4 com duas linhas, Brand alinhado na esquerda, social à direita e navegação na linha de baixo

[image: 2 rows nav]

Comment: Podes sempre usar um Nav dentro de uma section ou div, ou entao dois nav(um nav dentro de outro)

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">         
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a> 
    <div class="mr-sm-2">
        social
    </div>
</nav>  
<div class="row">      
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">item ativo</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">item 3</a>
          </li>          
        </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

`